# JUnit 5 - Parameterized test default display name with @CsvSource when the parameter is an user defined class

Tags: java, junit5

I have a parameterized test that uses an user defined class as the parameter,

```
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({ "1 a", "2 b" })
    @Order(8)
    void csvSourceIntString(IntString is) {
    }
```

`IntString` is define as follows, notice that I defined `toString`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class IntString {
    int i;
    String s;

    public IntString(int i, String s) {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public IntString(String is) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
            i = scanner.nextInt();
            s = scanner.next();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "i=" + i + ",s=" + s;
    }
}
```

I was expecting the default display names of the tests to be

```
[1] i=1,s=a
[2] i=2,s=b
```

Instead, when I ran this in Eclipse, they are what is in `@CsvSource`

```
[1] 1 a
[2] 2 b
```

Is this expected?

BTW, `@MethodSource` gave me expected default display names.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the name of the parameterized test explicitely:

```
@ParameterizedTest(name = "[{index}] {0}")
@CsvSource({ "1 a", "2 b" })
@Order(8)
void csvSourceIntString(IntString is) {
}
```